# sort listview in descending order i.e. newly added item should be at top

Tags: android, listview

I have taken a list view, used async task to fetch the data in json format. I want to display newly added item at top of the list view. I tried some ways but not so better result. how to do this ?

Comment: Please share what ways you've tried. 1) Sort the data according to what? 2) does the API you are calling support a sorting feature?

Comment: i have written webservice in php to get the data, and that data get sticked to my listview using adapter, i have used pojo class. data is coming from database i.e. phpmyadmin. no sorting method is used in web service.

Comment: Okay, you could right a PHP method that would sort you MySQL data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you didn't provide any code, here's my answer:
Just use this line to add to the `ArrayList` or `List` you are using:

```
yourList.add(0, newObject)
```

and then call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.